# Problem While Using DataSource Property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am using DataSource Property to Bind the data into ComboBox using C# in the following manner:

```
          ComboBox1.DataSource=dt;//dt is the datatable which is having the values
          ComboBox1.DisplayMember="column1";
          ComboBox1.ValueMember="column2";
```

The Problem is that i having all the values in the DataSource of the ComboBox1 i.e.totally five values,But the ComboBox1 count is 1 ,Dont know Why?Can anyone help me,Thanks in advance....................

Comment: You *see* five items in the `ComboBox`, but `.Count` is returning 1, or your `DataSource` is expected to have 5 items, but only 1 appears in the `ComboBox`?

Comment: My DataSource is expected to have 5 items, but only 1 appears in the ComboBox.......................

Answer (score 2):

There's gotta be more to your problem than just those 3 lines of code. I can reproduce the scenario just fine and it's working. Here's a working code sample:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(int));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add("Value " + i.ToString(), i);
        }

        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Column1";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Column2";
    }
}
```

It produces the following form:
[image: Form screenshot]